# "in a raft of magazines"

Tags: word-meaning

Now, I happened to be reading the Wiki about [Sylvia Plath,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvia_Plath) who was a "suicidal poet".

And I am afraid I don't understand what the use of the word "raft" at the title.

Quote ( from Works part in Wiki )

> Plath wrote poetry from the age of eight, her first poem appearing in the Boston Traveller.[2] By the time she arrived at Smith College she had written over 50 short stories and published **in a raft of magazines.**

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the meanings of the word *raft* is given as:

a large number or range; a lot:
a raft of data

We have designed a whole raft of measures to improve the transport system.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/raft

Comment: Thank you very much. a large amount or number of something:

His plan is to encourage more personal investment with a raft of tax breaks.
Congress is working to complete a raft of spending measures for the new fiscal year.
A whole raft of new guidelines and legislation is being introduced.